# What does which's --tty-only option do?

Tags: bash, which

I just realized that my sysadmin has created a global alias for `which`:

```
alias which='alias | /usr/bin/which --tty-only --read-alias --show-dot --show-tilde'
```

The `which` manpage just says:

> Stop processing options on the right if not on tty.

What does this mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Setup:

```
$ /usr/bin/which --show-dot a
./a
$ /usr/bin/which --show-tilde a
~/a
```

If you wanted the `.` version when run interactively, but the `~` version when redirected, you would could use this as an alias:

```
/usr/bin/which --show-tilde --tty-only --show-dot
```

Demo:

```
# interactive / on a tty
$ /usr/bin/which --show-tilde --tty-only --show-dot a
./a
# not interactive / redirected to a file
$ /usr/bin/which --show-tilde --tty-only --show-dot a > output
$ cat output 
~/a
```

All the options you specify after `--tty-only` are taken into account only when the output is a tty.

Comment: Nice! I did't realise `which` can do fancy things I always figured it for as dull a tool as there are.

Comment: It is a dull tool on my Ubuntu 13.4 box, it only has the `-a` option

Comment: @Gerard: see Sukminder's answer. Debian-based systems don't have those features. There are workarounds in the bug linked.

Answer (score 3):

That would mean that if output for `which` does ***not*** refer to a terminal, 
then do ***not*** process `--read-alias`, `--show-dot` and `--show-tilde`.

Typically if to a pipe, ordinary file etc.

```
which watch | foo # not a tty
which watch > foo # not a tty
which watch       # tty
which watch >&2   # tty
```

The options are not recognized under e.g. [debian](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=254292):